# Time complexity of nested while with changing condition

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve the complexity of this loop

```
for(int i= 0; i < n; i++) {    
 c = i;    
 while(c > 1){     
  O(1);     
  c = c / 2;     
 }    
}
```

as the while condition changes in every loop I don't know how to calculate that strange series.

I mean, if the loop where

```
for(int i= 0; i < n; i++) {     
 c = n;     
 while(c > 1){     
  O(1);     
  c = c / 2;     
 }
}
```

I know the while has a complexity of O(logn) and it repeats itself n times, so the complexity would be O(nlogn).

The problem I have with previous loop is "c=i". As c=i, first time (c=0) the loop would reproduce 0 times, when c=1 it would reproduce 0 times again, when c=2 it would reproduce 1 time, then the series would follow and it is 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3... (while reproductions each time of for loop)

O(logn) would not repeat itself n times, would repeat a number of times I can't come up with, so I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This need a bit of math involved.Given that log is well defined for a and b:

```
log(a) + log(b) = log(ab)
```

Here you have

```
log(1) + log(2) +....+ log(n) = log(1*....*n) = log(n!)
```

There is a [mathematical approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for log(n!), namely

```
 log(n!) ~ nlog(n) - n + 1
```

which reveal `O(log(n!)= O(nlog(n))`

Comment: why the complexity is "log(1) + log(2) +....+ log(n)"? shouldn't it be "log(1) + log(2) +....+ log(n-1)" as 'for' condition is i<n?

Comment: @Dgrm what's the difference. I can use the convention j = i+1. j goes from 1 to n while i goes from 0 to n-1